# PowerShell Invoke-AzOperationalInsightsQuery Error

Tags: windows, azure, powershell

When trying to use Invoke-AzOperationalInsightsQuery I get the following error

> Invoke-AzOperationalInsightsQuery: The term 'Invoke-AzOperationalInsightsQuery' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
> Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

I am not too sure on how to fix this issue, any help is welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[`Invoke-AzOperationalInsightsQuery` Cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.operationalinsights/invoke-azoperationalinsightsquery?view=azps-6.4.0) is part of [`Az` PowerShell module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-6.4.0) and not part of default PowerShell environment. You can [install it via `Install-Module` Cmdlet.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-6.4.0#installation) Or using [MSI package installer.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps-msi?view=azps-6.4.0#install-or-update-on-windows-using-the-msi-package)

```
Install-Module -Name Az -Scope CurrentUser -Repository PSGallery -Force
```